# Slow detection of large Aztec using MLKit and CameraX

Tags: java, barcode-scanner, google-mlkit

vision-quickstart detection of Aztec with high density is very slow. Read that increasing input image resolution should speed things up, but I don't know how to do that in the quickstart example.
I'm evaluating MLKit and some other frameworks for use in my scanner app.

Does any on know how to do that?

Trying to read Aztec on a electronic train ticket from mobile phone screen with MLKit qiuckstart example. Eventually it manages to detect it, but it takes about 10 to 30 seconds. The app is used for scanning Aztec code on train tickets.

Phones used to scan
Galaxy XCover 5 Android version 13
Galaxy A12 Android version 11

[image: Aztec qr-code]

Answer (score 0):

> Try this. It works well on my Galaxy XCover 5 to read the format
> (4096), but not  the text (getRawValue()) for that format. Don't know
> why! No problem with QR-Code and Barcode EAN-13.

```
@ExperimentalGetImage //Notice: @ExperimentalGetImage.
public class BarCodeImageAnalyzer implements ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

    private final BarcodeScanner scanner;

    public BarCodeImageAnalyzer() {

         scanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient();

    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void analyze(@NonNull ImageProxy imageProxy) {

        Image mediaImage = imageProxy.getImage();

        if (mediaImage != null) {
            InputImage image =
                    InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, rotation);
// rotation coding in main class according to ML-Kit instructions.
// https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/barcode-scanning/android.

            scanner.process(image)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(barcodes -> {
                        for (Barcode barcode : barcodes) {
                             codebarres.setText(""+barcode.getFormat());
                            // codebarres.setText(barcode.getRawValue());
// codebarres is a TextView in the mainactivity layout.
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnCompleteListener(results -> imageProxy.close());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not get your suggestion to work.

Comment: I've tested it (snippet) on AZTEC codes of different sizes but short text. It works well. What is the size of the posted aztecode? Can you read that aztecode anoher way?

Comment: Check out this site for testing your app: https://products.aspose.app/barcode/generate/aztec.

Comment: The content of my Aztecode is an encrypted text with ticket information. The aztec is read from a mobile device. I have no problem reading it on a computerscreen if a zoom up. But on a mobile device it is much smaller.